# iPhone - How to build a list of unique items

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want an array which contains only unique items.  I know I could do this with an NSDictionary adding items with keys and then get allKeys.  This would ensure that the NSArray contains only unique items, but I feel that this would be overkill and believe that there should be an easier way to do this, but cannot find one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSArray* uniqueArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:originalArray] allObjects];
```

Uniqueness is based on the isEqual: method.

Comment: Shouldn't that be NSArray *uniqueArray = [[NSSet withWithArray:originalArray] allObjects];

Answer (score 2):

Use NSSet or NSMutableSet for this. Keep in mind that uniqueness will be based on object address if you don't override the `isEqual:` method. Unless, of course, you are using classes that implement that method (`NSNumber`, `NSValue`, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSSet](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this